# query a table so that results are combined and returned in rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I need to pull data for a report so that columnar data is now row data:

```
empID  planID  coverage
-----  ------  --------
15     1       100
15     11      200
15     12      NULL    
15     13      500
20     1       100
20     11      250
20     12      400
20     13      NULL
```

Becomes:

```
emp  Basic  Supplemental  Spouse  Dependent
---  -----  ------------  ------  ---------
15   100    200                   500
20   100    250           400
```

I've tried various JOINS and best case scenerio get 4x the number of results since it repeats for each line in the former table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
CASE benefitSelected.planID WHEN 1 THEN benefitSelected.coverageLev END AS Basic, 
CASE benefitSelected_1.planID WHEN 11 THEN benefitSelected_1.coverageLev END AS Supplemental,
CASE benefitSelected_2.planID WHEN 12 THEN benefitSelected_2.coverageLev END AS Spouse,
CASE benefitSelected_3.planID WHEN 13 THEN benefitSelected_3.coverageLev END AS Dependent
FROM benefitSelected AS benefitSelected_3
  FULL OUTER JOIN benefitSelected AS benefitSelected_2 ON benefitSelected_3.empID = benefitSelected_2.empID
  FULL OUTER JOIN benefitSelected AS benefitSelected_1 ON benefitSelected_2.empID = benefitSelected_1.empID
  FULL OUTER JOIN benefitSelected
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN employee ON benefitSelected.empID = employee.empID
  ON benefitSelected_1.empID = benefitSelected.empID
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I get the results I want?

Thank you for your kind attention!

EDIT:
Results from PIVOT query below

```
--  --------  ---------  ----  --------
1   10000.00  NULL       NULL  NULL 
1   NULL      0.00       NULL  NULL
1   NULL      NULL       0.00  NULL
1   NULL      NULL       NULL  0.00
8   10000.00  NULL       NULL  NULL
8   NULL      100000.00  NULL  NULL
8   NULL      NULL       0.00  NULL
8   NULL      NULL       NULL  10000.00
```

Should be:

```
--  --------  ---------  ----  --------
1   10000.00  0.00       0.00  0.00
8   10000.00  100000.00  0.00  10000.00
```

Comment: Why not use pivot tables in SQL Server. Check [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx) for example

Comment: I still get four rows...which was the original problem...is it the code? SELECT empID,levID,[1],[11],[12],[13] FROM benefitSelected pivot(COUNT(coverageLev) FOR planID in ([1],[11],[12],[13])) AS planType

Comment: Can you past the result your getting

Comment: @EmmanuelN  Couldn't get formatting to stick in comments so have posted in the original question.  Results are similar to those from the original query.  (headers are as follows:  empID, 1, 11, 12, 13)
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT empID,
               coverage,
               CASE planID
                 WHEN 1 THEN 'Basic'
                 WHEN 11 THEN 'Supplemental'
                 WHEN 12 THEN 'Spouse'
                 WHEN 13 THEN 'Dependent'
               END PlanDesc
        FROM   benefitSelected) AS A PIVOT (Sum([coverage]) FOR [PlanDesc] IN ([Basic], [Supplemental], [Spouse], [Dependent])) p
```

Query returns:

```
empID   Basic   Supplemental    Spouse  Dependent
15      100     200             NULL    500
20      100     250             400     NULL
```